# Is Processing (2d graphics) appropriate for larger projects?

Tags: java, graphics, clojure, 2d, processing

I'm going to be working on a decent-sized game in clojure and for now it will have 2d graphics. Is Processing (or rather, Quil, which is just a clojure wrapper for Processing) an appropriate tool to use for this.

Processing presents itself as a way to quickly experiment with different ways of generating and manipulating graphics rather than a scalable 2d graphics library, but I don't see any obvious reasons why it couldn't be used as such, so long as you take care to properly separate logic code from rendering code.

If there are better options, let me know.

Comment: What sort of game? This makes quite a bit of difference to what sort of graphics library you need......

Comment: @mikera it's tile-based, where the player can interact with a lot of the tiles.

Comment: I'm working on a visualization project, and Processing works perfectly. [here](https://vimeo.com/37891411) is a first preview of it.

Answer (score 2):

Processing is certainly cool, but is somewhat specialised towards visualisation / interactive animations. It also has it's own mini-language designed for visualization applications. While it is possible you could make a decent game using it, you might start running into performance issues as this is going outside its usual usage.

For a decent-sized game I expect you will ultimately want to use OpenGL directly, in which case [LWJGL](http://www.lwjgl.org/) might be a better option.

Ultimately, you probably need to prototype using both and figure out what works best. As a rough benchmark, you will want to render a full screen of tiles plus 1,000 sprites at 100+ FPS with less than 20% CPU. If you can demonstrate that processing can handle that then you may be fine.

Other options that you can consider:

- Swing - good for simple 2D games. Has the advantage that it is built-in to the standard Java distribution and has lots of good tutorials. Wasn't really designed for games but works fine providing you aren't too demanding.
- JavaFX 2.0 - roughly intended to plat in the same space as Flash (rich internet applications). Looks pretty cool, but is still fairly new. Again, probably fine for simple Flash-style games.

Comment: how does using swing drawing compare to processing? I'm very new to the JVM ecosystem, so I'm pretty much clueless.

Comment: Swing is fine for GUIs and simple 2D games. I wouldn't use if for high performance games or complex graphics where you need special effects.

Answer (score 0):

I would be careful of using processing for this. I'm not sure about PC, but on the Mac Processing can have pretty hi CPU usage, depending what you are doing. So if your game is cross platform there might be a better option. If it's an online game why not use Flash? The scripting languages are not too far apart and in the book 'Processing: A programming handbook for visual Designers and Artists' (Casey Reas & Ben Fry) there's a handy little section at the back (pages 686 - 691) showing the comparative syntax of Processing, Java, Actionscript & Lingo that would be a useful way of getting you started.

Comment: I was initially going to do it in javascript, with a connection to a server via socket.io, but I chose to do it in clojure because I've just been learning the language and want to make something interesting with it.